# WP8 Some images not downloading using HttpClient

Tags: windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I am building a WP8 app that downloads images using HttpClient in a background task. My problem is that some images are not downloaded no matter how much time I wait for them to finish. The image sizes are a few megabytes at maximum.

The code I use to download images:

```
    internal static async Task<bool> Download_Wallpaper(string image_url, string file_name, string destination_folder_name)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                // 12MB max images
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit / 2;
                //client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

                byte[] image_byte_arr;
                try
                {
                    /*  var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Get, image_url );
                        var responseMessage = await client.SendAsync((requestMessage));
                        // byte array of image
                        image_byte_arr = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                        */
                    // byte array of image
                    image_byte_arr = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(image_url);
                }
                // Could not download
                catch (OutOfMemoryException X)
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                    return false;
                }

                var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(destination_folder_name);
                // Create file
                StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(file_name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                using (var write_stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    write_stream.Write(image_byte_arr, 0, image_byte_arr.Length);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException X)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(X);
            return false;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException X)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception X)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(X);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is an example image that fails to download: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Tracy_Caldwell_Dyson_in_Cupola_ISS.jpg

In my experience all wikimedia images fail to download for some reason.

I see no way of tracking download progress using HttpClient. Is there a way to do so?

**Edit:** It seems that setting the timeout does not have any function. The HttpRequestException is not thrown after 5 seconds.

**Edit2:** I tried a different approach, the one that anonshankar suggested. With that method the code would get stuck at the line:

```
byte[] img = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

So the HttpResponse arrives, but somehow the bytes could not be read out, no matter how much time I gave it. **How could this even happen? The hard part is getting the response, reading out the bytes should be simple.**

*Again, this only happens with some images, most of them downloads correctly. One example is mentioned above.*

I have modified my image downloader code, so that it times out after a few seconds. Here is my final code:

```
    internal static async Task<bool> Download_Wallpaper(string image_url, string file_name, string destination_folder_name)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                // prevent running out of memory
                client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit / 3;

                byte[] image_byte_arr = null;


                using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
                {

                    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            image_byte_arr = client.GetByteArrayAsync(image_url).Result;
                        }
                        catch (AggregateException X)// Handling read errors, usually image is too big
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(X.Message);
                            foreach (var v in X.InnerExceptions)
                                Console.WriteLine(v.Message);
                            image_byte_arr = null;
                        }
                    }, cts.Token);

                    bool finished_in_time = task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

                    if (!finished_in_time)// Timeout
                    {
                        cts.Cancel();
                        task.Wait();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (image_byte_arr == null)// Read error
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }

                var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(destination_folder_name);
                // Create file
                StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(file_name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                using (var write_stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    write_stream.Write(image_byte_arr, 0, image_byte_arr.Length);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException X)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(X);
            return false;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException X)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception X)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(X);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Any improvement suggestions are welcome, and I still don't understand why does the method *HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()* gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Just try out this `snippet` which worked for me.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("give the url");

byte[] img = response.Content.ReadAsByteArray();

InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));

writer.WriteBytes(img);

await writer.StoreAsync();

BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();

b.SetSource(randomAccessStream);

pic.Source = b; //(pic is an `<Image>` defined in the `XAML`
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello. Are you sure, this is WP8 code? I am asking, because in WP8 there is no ReadAsByteArray() method of HttpContent. Plus BitmapImage class can not be used in a background thread, only on a UI thread. I have previously tried very similar code to this anyway, did not work any better.